# How to sent some more information on click to the add to cart in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart.

I have an add to cart button. so when the user clicks on it then it will send the product information to the controller. Now I am just sending the information to the jQuery. It's just for testing purpose after some time I will send it to the controller using Ajax.

SO when I click on the button

```
<button type="button" name="addtocart" class="btn btn-success add_cart" data-productname="" data-price="" data-productid=""  />Add to cart</button>
```

then it sends the below information to the jQuery. I just want to know is there any more option. I mean I have to add some `user_id, username` etc.

```
data-productname
data-price
data-productid

    $('.add_cart').click(function(){
      var product_name = $(this).data("productname");
      var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
      var product_price = $(this).data("price");
      var quantity =1;
//data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price,quantity:quantity},
    )};
```

In the controller, I am displaying the details

```
 $data = array(
   "id"  => $_POST["product_id"],
   "name"  => $_POST["product_name"],
    "qty"  => $_POST["quantity"],
   "price"  => $_POST["product_price"]
  );
```

Comment: Is there any reason on why you have to send extra data than only an id and quantity?

Comment: You should send only mandatory input to maintain security ,integrity and performance

Comment: Why I am doing is because I am the primary member and I have more then 1 a secondary member. I want to send the secondary id to the cart to know that which secondary member is choose.